# RegEx start with, contains these, not end with?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to find all comparison parts  in the following example.

```
        var magicalRegex = "";
        var example = '({Color}=="red"|{Color}=="yellow")&{Size}>32';
        example.replace(magicalRegex, function (matchedBlock) {
            console.log(matchedBlock);
        });

        //so i want to see the following result on console 
        //{Color}=="red"
        //{Color}=="yellow"
        //{Size}>32
```

In fact i did some things but couldn't complete, also  you may check the following template which i couldn't complete.

```
\{.*?(==|>)
```

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/aodDeX/1

Thanks

Comment: i need a new search engine that beats google, can you give it to me? SO is not a free coding service, nor a tutorial website. Please attempt to solve the problem by yourself, and when you get stuck after trying different ways, then post on SO. Thanks

Comment: `({.*?}(?:==|>)(?:\d+|(?:(["']?).*?\2)))`?

Comment: I moved my previous comment to an answer.

Comment: @kadir950 You should post all relevant code in stackoverflow for the purpose of future views. Let's say, for example, regex101 goes down (i.e. not enough funding), users can still see what you've tried and they can test it on regex102 (or whatever supercedes the previous link). Linking to regex101 is still very beneficial but it does allow for a sort of backup of your code.

Comment: @ctwheels  you are right, I consider your advice. Thank you.

Comment: @kadir950 Looks much better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

According to the example you have on regex101 as well as the string you have in your code snippet (two different strings) the following regex will do exactly what you want.

#### Answer 1

```
({.*?}(?:==|>)(?:\d+|(?:(["']?).*?\2)))
```

You can see this regex in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/UeHtNA/1)

#### Answer 2

Note that I've added both single and double quotes in the above regex. If you only need double quotes, use the following regex.

```
({.*?}(?:==|>)(?:\d+|".*?"))
```

You can see this regex in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/UeHtNA/2)

#### Explanation

These regular expressions work as follows:

1. Match `{`, followed by any character (except newline) any number of times, but as few matches as possible, followed by `}`
2. Match `==` or `>`
3. Match a digit one to unlimited times or match a quoted string (any character any number of times, but as few matches as possible) e.g. `"something"`

The regex captures the entire section and if you look at the examples on regex101 as presented, you can see what each capture group is matching. You can remove the capture groups if this is not the intended use.

---

### Expected Results

#### Input

Note that the two strings below were used for testing purposes. One string is present in the question and the other is present in the link provided by the OP.

```
({Renk}=="kirmizi"or{Renk}=="sari")or{Size}>32
({Color}=="red"|{Color}=="yellow")&{Size}>32
```

#### Output

Note that the output mentioned hereafter specifies what is matched/also capture group 1 (since the whole regex is in a capture group). Any other groups are disregarded as they are not important to the overall question/answer.

```
{Renk}=="kirmizi"
{Renk}=="sari"
{Size}>32

{Color}=="red"
{Color}=="yellow"
{Size}>32
```

Comment: Matches `{Renk=="sari")or{Size}>32`

Comment: @sln which one? Both have links to regex101 and both perform as presented above

Comment: Answer 2 is exactly what i need. I also corrected the mistake in my question. Thank you so much @ctwheels for your detailed and helpful answer.

Comment: @sln The code you posted has invalid syntax. The brackets/parentheses don't match.

Comment: I didn't post code. I showed you a target _your_ regex matches. If it matches invalid syntax, so be it.

Comment: @sln I'm assuming, of course, the syntax is always valid. I could edit my regex to catch these syntax errors but I believe it's beyond the scope of this question since the OP didn't ask to validate the string, but instead to catch variables within it.

Comment: @ctwheels Yes the purpose is catching variable parts . > {key}==val

Comment: It's usually implied some form of validation is included in all regex.

Comment: @ctwheels  I modified your regex to catch blocks without fancy brackets and also with decimal values as below. What do you think for it, is it best way?   


Regex> (\w.*?(?:==|>)(?:\d\.\d|\d+|".*?"))

String> 'Size>3.2&(Color=="red"|Color=="yellow")'

https://regex101.com/r/UeHtNA/3

Comment: @kadir950 you should instead use the following regex: `(\w+(?:==|>)(?:\d+\.?\d*|".*?"))`. This regex will catch numbers and decimals (if any) of any length and in valid formats. Your regex will only catch single digit number/decimal combinations such as `3.2` but it will not catch `10.2`, instead it'll catch `10` since your decimal check is not setup correctly. Also, the dot near the beginning of your regex is sort of useless since you know each variable name consists of only `\w` characters. The `.` that follows it would cause you issues.

Comment: @kadir950 I'm not quite sure what you mean by comment the regex. Do you want me to add that regex to my answer as another alternative to include things wrapped in square brackets `[` `]`?

Comment: Hi @ctwheels, is it also possible to find mathematical expression blocks  in the same expression? I couldn't find mathematical expression blocks with normal condition blocks at same time.   Last form of exp: https://regex101.com/r/UeHtNA/7       
`(\w+(?:==|!=|>|<|>=|<=)(?:\d+\.?\d*|".*?"|\[.*?\]|null))`  for     **(C25-C2)!=15** && **(C12+C25*(C45/C8))<12**    Thanks.

Comment: @kadir950 not quite sure what you mean, what are you trying to catch in that string?

Comment: @ctwheels   In addition to standard condition  blocks,  I also want to catch this  mathematical expression block.
Kindly check: Js Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbypzJ   and
Screenshot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AjgdoJ6rjf_OjGfcdoPM2cp88-2q

Comment: @kadir950 Honestly, this cannot be easily achieved with JavaScript. It has more limitations in terms of regex than most languages do. If this was done with PCRE regex (i.e. PHP), it would be more easily achievable. Your best bet is to create a proper parser and use multiple regular expressions to parse the information you're looking for.